# `RawAutoComplete` use Enter key as a keyboard shortcut for selecting an option

Tags: flutter, dart

How is it possible to use Enter key as a keyboard shortcut for selecting an option of `RawAutoComplete`? I have seen that it is possible without registering a separate shortcut, but I couldn't find out how.

[GitHub topic](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94488#issuecomment-984057766)

Comment: When I run the demo on the [`RawAutocomplete` documentation page](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RawAutocomplete-class.html), pressing Enter to select an option works fine. Do you have code where it isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have found out what the problem was - I was using `TextField` instead of `TextFormField` in `fieldViewBuilder` of `RawAutoComplete` and therefore not passing `onFieldSubmitted` callback to the field. That's why Enter key didn't work.